# Centering inside a variable size container that is not full width?

Tags: html, css, layout, center, multiple-columns

I've found many answers to centering a variable size div, but I want to center a div **inside** a variable size div. I haven't been able to find any help on this matter.

Essentially, my wrapper is divided into two columns. Left one with a fixed width and right one that is supposed to fill in the rest of the screen. I've got this worked out.

Now, I would like to place another div in the middle (both vertical and horizontal) of the right column. You can find an illustration of my goal [**HERE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSIow.png).

[**THIS**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CjJyg) is what I've got so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">     
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <section role="main">
      <article>
        <h1>Title</h1>
          <p>Paragraph</p>
      </article>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

LESS:

```
html, body { 
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: #333;
    font: normal normal 12px/18px @font;
    color: @text;   
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  min-width: 800px;
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background: @c2;
}

.right {
  margin-left: 250px;
    background: @c1;
    height: 100%;

    article {
    height: 300px;
        width: 500px;
        background: #fff;
    }

}
```

My goal is to get the white article -element in the middle of the yellowish one.

What I've tried:

- display:table -technique found at emergentweb.com/test/valign.html
- ghost-child -technique fount at css-tricks.com

Is this even possible?

I don't really mind JS / jQuery, but I'd prefer not to use them.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lEbHD - Codepen doesn't render it right, add to your actual page.

Comment: post some code here also, not just in external links please.

Comment: Kyle, that seems to nudge the whole site up with the margin-top. I applied this to my site (local testing environment) and it shows up just like in the Codepen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this css property

```
.right article{
margin:auto;
}
```

Or you can do this.

If the div you want to center is 500px, do this.

To the parent div, apply `position:relative` and to de div you want to center apply

```
.right article{
position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-250px;
}
```

This mechanism also works for vertical centering.

Comment: Cheers piruchex! The second method seems to work. I simply added top:50%; and margin-top as well and it was complete. Thanks!